# Determining parameter types of WCF method when using IDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest

Tags: c#, wcf-rest

We have a custom IDispatchMessageFormatter (which can be applied using an attribute to any specific method) for handling JSON requests to and from our RESTful WCF services.  I've implemented the DeserializeRequest method but just need to determine, at runtime, what type to convert the querystring parameters to.  For example, if the method is:

```
[MyCustomOperationBehavior]
[WebGet("/thethings/{thing1}/{thing2}/{number1}")]
public MyReturnThing Foo(string thing1, string thing2, int number1)
```

I need to know that the 3rd parameter in the WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.BoundVariables collection is supposed to be an int.  The WCF stack can obviously do this, but I'm unsure how to get access to the method being called from within the dispatch formatter.  Any help with this would be much appreciated!